# One common header table or separate header tables for following scenario?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am developing a website by using ASP.NET and backend is MYSQL. PHP users If you dealt with this please contribute your idea also.

In my website users can post articles and articles are categorized.
Currently I am using below database structure.
[image]

When ever a user post an article to the website common things for article (title,description) are stored in the header table and specific details are store in specific category table.
But let assume that in a given instance category 1,2,3,4 have 100,000 records in each category. by simple math we know that the header table contain 400,000 records. Understood?
I am maintaining a user account and when an user log to his account he can view what are the articles are posted into categories and I am showing only titles of the articles. This is possible with no joins because I retrieve those from header table.
Ok. So those category and header tables are main production tables. Among those Header table is the busiest one because no matter what category you choosing it is use by every category table.
So day by day this header table is increasing.
This is the approach currently I am using.

---

This is my 2nd approach which is just an idea.
Take a look at this image.
[image]

In here I am maintaining 4 header tables for each category. So those header table will contain only the data of each category. And I am maintaining a main header table for user account process. This table will also contain title as well as what is the equivalent header table for the article. So at this time Main header table is not a production table. It is access only from user account. When user  select category 1 in articles display window he is only dealing with that category 1 table and equivalent small header table.
So which is best? Do I need to worry about my current approach in future when I am dealing with massive amount of records?

(Assume database schema of these header tables will not change frequently. So forget about difficulty of maintain. I will handle it. My main target is the performance. I am using bigint datatype for the primary keys of every table. I used indexes)

Give me an intelligent, Long term, Business wise answer who already dealing with massive data storage. Provide me any links to refer and backup your answers please. Thank you very much.

Comment: what [tag:php] doing here?

Comment: This is not about php or asp.net bro. Its mainly about database structure. If you dealt with this type scenario you are most welcome for your idea. :)

Comment: tags are used for relevant information to the subject. i am editing this one out for ya.